# Switzerland - sleeping in the car?

Tags: legal, switzerland, road-trips, sleeping

Is it allowed in Switzerland to sleep in the car (2 people, small car, in small vilages)? I want to go there (near Lozana) but I have not much money, so I don't want to spent it on hostels. Is it possible?

Comment: You can sleep for one night (sometimes for 12h max) on a motorway rest area. That's what truckers do.

Comment: I'm not sure if ordinary motorists are actually allowed to do that, @JoErNanO.   Also: are you perfectly sure that **in Switzerland** truckers are in fact allowed to do that in any old rest area?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [Trip Adviser forum](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g188045-i336-k10506237-Overnighting_in_Switzerland_with_your_Camper-Switzerland.html):

> it is not legal to spend a night in a camping car/van/caravan etc
>   outside of a designated camp ground here in switzerland. You need to
>   get a list of camp sites and plan your trip accordingly.

However, another individual did also comment:

> Ticino is part of Switzerland and it seems to be legal at least to
>   sleep in your car overnight. You have to remove the keys from the
>   ignition and put them away otherwise you can be fined though.

However, this [website](https://www.zuerich.com/en/visit/driving-in-switzerland) states:

> It is generally not permitted to stay overnight in a car on a public
>   parking lot. It is therefore recommended to find a campground or any
>   other accommodation where you can spend the night. In some regions,
>   sleeping for one night in the car is tolerated. You can ask at the
>   local police station for more information.

From just a general observation, it seems that it would not be advisable to sleep in your car overnight.

Comment: Yeah, the trick is "designated area", which usually means" where you have toilet available (like parking on service areas and rest areas on highways). On small village is worst: you doesn't spend money there, but you cost (waste, touristic attractions, paths). And it can seems that you are just waiting night for burglary.